# XNA C# Getting Input from a EXE file

Tags: c#, process, xna, redirectstandardoutput

I am writing a multidimensional array from xna and i need 3 values before I create it from the user. In `Initialize()` I used

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
            p.FileName = @"C:\Sean\Adventures!\PlayerInput.exe";
            p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.UseShellExecute = false;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(p))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                }
            }
```

the playerinput exe file is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("# of layers?");
            int layers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("# of rows?");
            int rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("# of columns?");
            int columns = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```

I know there is a way to do this, but I am having immense trouble. How can I execute an exe from a XNA C# code and receive int layer, row and columns?

Comment: You are redirecting the console output, so the user will see nothing. Instead of reading the output stream from the process, launch the console app, that app then can write to a file the values, the XNA program can then wait for the process to finish and then you can read the file.